# Long string matching in the same or other records

Tags: awk

I need to find repeated strings those are more than 7 characters long. The complete paragraph (verse) should be returned so that I know the context. For e.g. in the following text, the string 'सर्वभूतहिते रताः' is repeated in first and last para (5-25 and 12-4)

Sample Text:

```
लभन्ते ब्रह्मनिर्वाणमृषयः क्षीणकल्मषाः ।
छिन्नद्वैधा यतात्मानः सर्वभूतहिते रताः ॥ ५-२५॥

दृष्ट्वा तु पाण्डवानीकं व्यूढं दुर्योधनस्तदा ।
आचार्यमुपसङ्गम्य राजा वचनमब्रवीत् ॥ १-२॥

पश्यैतां पाण्डुपुत्राणामाचार्य महतीं चमूम् ।
व्यूढां द्रुपदपुत्रेण तव शिष्येण धीमता ॥ १-३॥

अन्ये च बहवः शूरा मदर्थे त्यक्तजीविताः ।
नानाशस्त्रप्रहरणाः सर्वे युद्धविशारदाः ॥ १-९॥

अपर्याप्तं तदस्माकं बलं भीष्माभिरक्षितम् ।
पर्याप्तं त्विदमेतेषां बलं भीमाभिरक्षितम् ॥ १-१०॥

अभिसन्धाय तु फलं दम्भार्थमपि चैव यत् ।
इज्यते भरतश्रेष्ठ तं यज्ञं विद्धि राजसम् ॥ 17.12॥

अयनेषु च सर्वेषु यथाभागमवस्थिताः ।
भीष्ममेवाभिरक्षन्तु भवन्तः सर्व एव हि ॥ १-११॥

सत्कारमानपूजार्थं तपो दम्भेन चैव यत् ।
क्रियते तदिह प्रोक्तं राजसं चलमध्रुवम् ॥ 17.18॥

सन्नियम्येन्द्रियग्रामं सर्वत्र समबुद्धयः ।
ते प्राप्नुवन्ति मामेव सर्वभूतहिते रताः ॥ १२-४॥
```

Expected output is:

```
लभन्ते ब्रह्मनिर्वाणमृषयः क्षीणकल्मषाः ।
छिन्नद्वैधा यतात्मानः सर्वभूतहिते रताः ॥ ५-२५॥

सन्नियम्येन्द्रियग्रामं सर्वत्र समबुद्धयः ।
ते प्राप्नुवन्ति मामेव सर्वभूतहिते रताः ॥ १२-४॥
```

The paragraphs are always separated by line break \n and therefore blank line can be (Input and output) **Record Separator**.
The repeated text can be found on the same line but can not overlap.

For e.g. in this text:

```
extremely this is a sample this extremely|
and one more line||

that is a another that |
and junk more text ||
```

The first two lines should return:

```
extremely this is a sample this extremely|
and one more line||
```

Because "extremely" is a string more than 7 characters long and is repeated. The complete para (of 2 lines) is returned.

I have tagged only awk because in my experience that is the only language that works with large text files.

---

Update:

```
# cat file
extre mely this is a sample this extre mely|
and one more line||

that is a another that |
and junk more text ||

The paragraphs are always separated by line |
but this word extre mely match here||
```

I tried the script and I am getting only the first paragraph.

```
# awk -f tst.ak file
extre mely this is a sample this extre mely|
and one more line||
```

Because the string "extre mely" that is more than 6 characters long is present in 2 records. (First and Third)

```
# expected output:
extre mely this is a sample this extre mely|
and one more line||

The paragraphs are always separated by line |
but this word extre mely match here||
```

Let's assume the third record does not exist, then the first record (i.e. first 2 lines) should be returned. Because a string longer than 6 characters is repeated in that paragraph. The awk script mentioned in the answer is already doing this correctly.

Comment: What is the character set/character encoding? Unless it's UTF-8, you are in trouble. (you are not completely out of the woods if it is). What `awk` are you using? `gawk`, `mawk`, POSIX `awk`? See discussion [Using awk to detect UTF-8 multibyte character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61411478/3422102)

Comment: Stanzas 6 and 8 both contain the duplicate string `म् ॥ 17.`, seven characters long.   I think you mean something else: like duplicate verse text, not including the separating characters or verse labels.

Comment: Yes. Duplicate verse text preferred. This example "म् ॥ 17" is an exception. But I can delete it later. No problem.

Comment: I am trying to find repeated strings from a popular hindu script. 
https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/bhagvadnew.html

Comment: I am using # awk --version ## GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1) But I can install any other version if required.

Comment: Sample output can be found here. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hvASE46BtLdzJkVF63tbETjnRerTlFHqNRbOxZoQ8Lk/edit

Comment: An off-site link which requires us to have a Google account hidden in a comment is _not_ acceptable. Please [edit] the question to contain a (small) sample.

Comment: You do not need a Google account to check that document. It is just like any other website. Is it OK if I publish it on my blog and then link here? A (small) sample is already part of the question.

Comment: No, make sure your question contains all relevant information. No links, no images, just text. All we want/need is a [mcve] that demonstrates your requirements and we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with. Whatever aspects of the text available at those links is not already part of your sample input/output but needs to be to demonstrate and test your requirements, add a minimal sample of that to your example. If there is no such aspect then we don't need to see it.

Comment: I just noticed you said (emphasis mine) "matching in the same **or other records**". Are you saying that if `thisstring` appears in the first blank-line separated record and in the third blank-line separated record that one or both records should be printed? Your first example might be more useful if it was in English since this is an English-language site and so everyone would then be able to understand it instead of just the subset who also speak the language you're currently using in your example. Once it's working in English then you can test it with any other language, char set, locale...

Comment: OK; I made a solution that respect word boundaries. Only sequences of unbroken words are considered, containing seven or more non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions/Understandings

- if a (7-character) string occurs more than once in a file then we are to print each paragraph that contains said string
- with OP's lastest update (`file` contains 3 english paragraphs) we're told that `extre mely` should match on `extremely` (unless that's a typo in OP's sample input data); from this I'm assuming we're to ignore white space
- OP has also confirmed a comment/question:  *`I think you mean something else: duplicate verse text, not including the separating characters or verse labels`* which implies we're to ignore some characters

General approach:

- use `awk` to read `file` twice:
- 1st read: find all (7-character) strings and keep a count of how many times they occur in the file
- 1st read (completed): reduce our list of strings to only those that occur at least twice in the file
- 2nd read: print each paragraph that contains a (7-character) string (where the string occurs at least twice in the file)
- for the english version of `file` we'll ignore white space

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v minlen=7 '                                          # define min length of string
BEGIN   { RS = ""; ORS = "\n\n" }                          # define input (RS) and output (ORS) record separators

        { compact = $0                                     # all files, all records: make copy of current record
          gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",compact)                  # remove white space
          len = length(compact)
          lastpos = len - minlen + 1
        }

FNR==NR { for (i=1; i<=lastpos; i++)                       # 1st file, all records: parse current record character by character ...
              strings[substr(compact,i,minlen)]++          # keep count of each substring we process
          next
        }

FNR==1  { for (i in strings)                               # 2nd file, 1st record: loop through our array of strings ...
              if (strings[i] == 1)                         # if the string was only seen once then ...
                 delete strings[i]                         # delete the array entry
        }

        { for (i=1; i<=lastpos; i++)                       # 2nd file, all records: parse current record character by character ...
              if (substr(compact,i,minlen) in strings) {   # if the substring is an index in our array then ...
                 print                                     # print current record and ...
                 next                                      # skip to next record
              }
        }
' file file                                                # have awk read the file two times
```

**NOTE:** modify the `gsub(...)` line per requirements, eg:

- remove `gsub(...)` if we're to include white space
- replace/expand `gsub(...)` to filter out other characters and/or strings
- with additional coding it is possible to eliminate the requirement to have `awk` read the file twice (eg, during the 1st reading of the file we store paragraphs in an array, then in place of the 2nd reading of the file we iterate through the array of paragraphs)

This generates:

```
extre mely this is a sample this extre mely|
and one more line||

The paragraphs are always separated by line |
but this word extremely match here||
```

**NOTES:**

- for large(r) files you'll need to keep an eye on memory usage; for this tiny, 3-paragraph file the `strings[]` array required ~1.3 MB of memory in my system
- eliminating the excessive memory usage would require a significant increase in cpu usage, especially as the size of the file increases

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

```
$ txr duppara.tl < data
लभन्ते ब्रह्मनिर्वाणमृषयः क्षीणकल्मषाः ।
छिन्नद्वैधा यतात्मानः सर्वभूतहिते रताः ॥ ५-२५॥

सन्नियम्येन्द्रियग्रामं सर्वत्र समबुद्धयः ।
ते प्राप्नुवन्ति मामेव सर्वभूतहिते रताः ॥ १२-४॥
```

Code:

```
(defvarl h (hash))

(defun min-char-ngrams (min words)
  (append-each ((tail (conses words)))
    (buildn
      (let ((count 0))
        (while (and tail (< count min))
          (let ((w (pop tail)))
            (add w)
            (inc count (len w))))
        (if (>= count min)
          (list (get)))))))

(defstruct para ()
  text
  hit

  (:postinit (me)
    (let* ((ptext (match `@a ।\n@b ॥ @nil` me.text
                    `@a @b`))
           (words (spl " " ptext)))
      (each ((ng (min-char-ngrams 7 words)))
        (push me [h ng])))))

(flow (get-string)
  (spl "\n\n")
  (mapcar (opip (trim-right "\n")
                (new para text @1)))
  (let paras)
  (dohash (ng plist h)
    (if (rest plist)
      (each ((p plist))
        (set p.hit t))))
  (each ((p paras))
    (when p.hit
      (put-line p.text)
      (put-line))))
```

The approach here is:

- "Snarf" the entire input as a string
- Divide it into paragraphs, which becomes a sequence of `para` objects.
- The `para` object does most of the complex work in the initialization function: the text is first cleaned of delimiters and labels. Then it is broken into a sequence of words. From sequence of words we identify all n-grams subsequences that contain at least 7 characters (not including spaces).  All such n-grams are used as keys in a global hash table, whose values are lists of `para` objects that contain that n-gram. The lists contain possible repetititons.
- Having this hash table, we process all its entries. For those entries which list two or more `para` objects (meaning that the n-gram appears twice), we walk all the `para` objects and set their `hit` flag to true.
- With the `hit` flags set, we just walk the list of `para` objects and print the ones that are flagged.

Due to the way the text is cleaned, and the use of n-grams rather than blind substrings, the solution respects word boundaries, and avoids false positives arising from the extraneous text.

Comment: Not able to install TXR on Ubuntu 22.04 (ARM)

Comment: You're not trying to use Homebrew by any chance?

Comment: Can not install. Getting an error "Homebrew on Linux is not supported on ARM processors."

Comment: You dodged a bullet there. Homebrew builds a broken package of TXR that doesn't work. Users have also reported not being able to build the Homebrew formula at all.  TXR is an easy build: clone the repo `./configure && make && make tests && make install`. I don't have an ARM machine with Ubuntu, but I went through a build on a RISCV machine running Ubuntu 22; it was problem-free.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS = ""
    ORS = "\n\n"
    strLgth = 7
}
{
    delete cnt
    lineLgth   = length($0)
    endCharPos = lineLgth - strLgth + 1

    for ( tgtCharPos=1; tgtCharPos<=endCharPos; tgtCharPos++ ) {
        tgtStr = substr($0,tgtCharPos,strLgth)
        for ( curCharPos=tgtCharPos+strLgth; curCharPos<=endCharPos; curCharPos++ ) {
            curStr = substr($0,curCharPos,strLgth)
            if ( tgtStr == curStr ) {
                print
                next
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
अपर्याप्तं तदस्माकं बलं भीष्माभिरक्षितम् ।
पर्याप्तं त्विदमेतेषां बलं भीमाभिरक्षितम् ॥ १-१०॥
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2
extremely this is a sample this extremely|
and one more line||
```

I don't know if the different output from expected for that first set of input is because there's a bug in the script or the expected output is wrong as I don't speak the language or know where characters start/stop in the non-English example, you'll have to figure that out for yourself.